# Applying date format to v-model date value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

How can I format the date in my input? ex: I get this date value `2019-10-10T07:00:00Z` for this line of code `<input type="text" v-bind:data-id="program.id" :readonly="program.isReadOnly" v-model="program.Date">`  but I need it to be in this format mm/dd/yy

I created a method to use moment.js but it's not working completely.  It formats the date correctly but when I try to change it and save, it reverts back to the unwanted date.

```
<input type="text" v-bind:data-id="program.id" :readonly="program.isReadOnly" v-model="formatDate(program)">

 formatDate(program){
      var formatL = moment.localeData().longDateFormat('L');
      var format2digitYear = formatL.replace(/YYYY/g,'YY');
      return moment(program.Date).format(format2digitYear);
    }
```

Here's the [pen](https://codepen.io/isogunro/pen/bGGrWZG)

Comment: You can you filter for this approach. You should write one filter to format datetime https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-format-date-for-display/3586/3

Comment: How would I use that with an input element?